# Why do I get "Binding element 'store' implicitly has an 'any' type" here with TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have an array which contains 2 objects, I'd like to use `map` to pass each object to a Card. Here is the code:

The `IStores` interface:

```js
interface IStores {
  id: number;
  title: string;
}

export default IStores;
```

The `Card` component:

```js
const Card = ({ store }) => {
    return (
        <>
            <div className="card" key={store.id}>
                <div className='card-body'>
                    <h5 className="card-title">
                        {store.title}
                    </h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default Card;
```

The `Home` component which passes each object to `Card` with `map`:

```js
const storeDetails: IStores[] = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Store A'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Store B'
    }
]

const Home = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <div className='center-content'>
                <h1>Just shop local</h1>
                <div>
                    {
                        storeDetails.map(
                            (d) => {
                                return (
                                    <Card store={d} />
                                )
                            }
                        )
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default Home;
```

Now I've got an error in `Card` at line 1:

```
Binding element 'store' implicitly has an 'any' type
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Binding element 'store' implicitly has an 'any' type

This error is telling you that you have a variable without a type. So you have to type the props that `Card` expects. In this case, you might do that like:

```
interface Props {
  store: IStores
}

const Card = ({ store }: Props) => {
  //...
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChTgA7GJKTdJOASQGUZokBnOAb1LjjAAJgC44lAK4gARrQDc-ODGAwANkjGcYUKgHMFAX3JUadBnAAKOMNz4CtHMa3ZFOpI6TQRKWuAGEUKCE4AF44AAoeOAciOAMxKwgbAEpQgD5eRQEiGAkoSgisgWKAHjSi4sq4EqFgADc4NFUUTk4AORQQJBCAIjRAoR64AGskAE8QnhikADphA3Kqpaqa+sbm1o6ukPx+oIBaaQghMfxF5YvKkoALAFZ1lvbO7r6B-eU1JB7zy9-iqZcsw+6iMf0uJQA9HcfmDqhDanUYRdIQikaUITDku5yEgAB6QWBwIRIegSVTwAJBORwIA)

Comment: Is there a way not to define `Props`?

Comment: @thinkvantagedu Why would you not want to declare the type of the Props?

Comment: No. You have to.

Comment: @AlexWayne Because I thought something like this would work: `const Card = ({ store }: IStores) => {`

Comment: No. This syntax uses deconstructing assignment. `({ store }: Props)` is shorthand for `(props: Props)` followed by `const store = props.store`. So when you do `<Card store={d} />` that means that `Card` receives props as `{ store: IStores }`. You have to type the entire props argument, not just one prop.

Comment: @AlexWayne Thanks for the explanation!